# java script Sort method is not working on IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-8

i am working on google maps api in this i am  doing sorting using sort function it is working fine in all browsers but on IE 8 it is not working properly.
on console log i have seen it is returning a value "Undefined". can anybody give an idea or any alternate of sort method. Here is a part of my code.

```
        var branch= source.sort(function(a, b){
            return a.distance - b.distance;
        });
        return branch[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
source.sort(function(a, b){
            return a.distance==b.distance?0:(a.distance>b.distance?1:-1);
        });
return source[0];
```